# bulk insert using insert...select in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, bulkinsert

I have a list of users who should receive the message. They are in the table subscribe. Now I'd like to insert a message for every one of these users. My query is

```
insert into message(user, type, theId)
    select (select user from subscribe_message), @type, @id
```

At the moment it is empty. I get the error `message.user may not be NULL`. Shouldn't it not insert any rows? When I have more than one row it inserts the first row only. How do I write this so it will insert 0 to many rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO message ( user, type, theId )
SELECT  subscribe_message.user, @type, @id
FROM    subscribe_message
```

Comment: That works and looks much better then my original. Thanks (will accept when it allows me)